# I don't understand the expression 葉が震える

Tags: translation, meaning

A man is driving home a woman. At a certain point he does not see her in the rearmirror of his car. He discovers that the woman has vanished. Then he writes this: **葉が震え**、もう後を向く気がしなかった。

Has the expression in bold a particular meaning? I know it only as "leaves tremble" but here it does not make sense.

Comment: i'm thinking a bit more of the context might help.

Comment: 同じ話を載せている[このページ](https://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/v1hp1/diary/201602180000/)・[このページ](http://yoshizokitan.blog.shinobi.jp/Entry/13225/)では「 **歯**がふるえ、もううしろを振り向く気がしなかった。」になっていますね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a typo for **歯が震え**.(歯 and 葉 have the same pronunciation "は")

**歯が震える** (*lit.* [one's] teeth tremble) is used when you feel horror and are frightened.(or it is so cold that your teeth chatter.)